# Can Nodes in py2neo be inherited?

Tags: python, inheritance, flask, py2neo

I am building an application in Flask using py2neo as a graph database. I have a node for a generic item, and a node for a specific implementation of that item. What I want is that if I search for all the generic nodes, that the specific implementation of those nodes also appear in the results. I would usually just inherit the Node as an object, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575830/model-inheritance-in-neomodel-is-not-working), py2neo throws an exception. The answer given in that question is specific for Django, so it is not useful for me since I am using Flask.

How would this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to implement this by using `node.labels.add()` function as described in [this documentation](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#nodes) and just add labels to that node. It achieves the same purpose. This can also be done in Cypher as described in [this reference document](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.2/cypher-refcard/) by using the `SET n:Label` command.